# I have an requirement to get the Data in the Vertical format from Horizontal by using JCL?

Tags: zos, dfsort

```
INPUT FILE:
NAME      AADHAR NUMBER    MOBILE NUMBER
```

```
OUTPUT FILE:

NAME 
AADHAR NUMBER
MOBILE NUMBER
```

Comment: The question doesn’t really provide enough detail to help you.  Are you looking to take items from an input record and reorder them using something like SORT in batch ?

Comment: Actually using SORT can we do this requirement.    In the Input file, I have Horizontal and I want it in Vertical order. like INPUT FILE: name aadhar number mobile number

Comment: Yes, I wanna use SORT

Comment: I updated the formatting, does this represent what you are expecting?  To rephrase what you are asking for.  You have a single record as input with three fields ‘NAME’, ‘AADHAR NUMBER’, ‘MOBILE NIUMBER’ and you want to output three records for every input record with each output record containing one of the fields?   Is that correct ?

Comment: Please remove the `JCL` tag, since you cannot do this with JCL. You need a program like SORT, as you say, so add the `SORT` tag.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah, Hogstrom I have Data like this
INPUT FILE:( Vertical Data)
NAME      AADHAR NUMBER    MOBILE NUMBER
JHON         777777777777                6666666666
ROHAN      888888888888                9999999999
SAIRAM     555555555555                 4444444444

OUTPUT FILE (Horizontal Data)

NAME                              JHON                    ROHAN                  SAIRAM  
AADHAR NUMBER        777777777777       888888888888        555555555555
MOBILE NUMBER          6666666666            9999999999           4444444444

 I want the data like in the Output file.

Comment: Please I'm waiting for the answer still I'm not getting !!:(((